# Re-attaching source files to existing SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I recently had to re-install windows due to a faulty hard drive.. luckily I had all of my source files on another disk.

On my previous installation, I was using Tortoise SVN, which I've just re-installed on my new machine (a few months down the line).

How can I re-link my current source files to the SVN repository?

I'm worried that if I click the wrong thing, it will update my local copy with what's on the server.

Thanks
Rich.

Comment: Please explain, that is "your sources", how they correlate to the state of files in repo, there you have (had) your repositories. If you have only Working Copy without remote repository - you lost history

Comment: My 'source files' are the files that I am storing on SVN (source code files for c#). I still have everything intact on my new machine, and I've made changes to the code locally. The SVN still has the original versions, and all history. I think that the worst case scenario is that I have to check-out, then copy all of my updated files over the top, then do an update, but was hoping for a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You first need to create a *working directory* and the only way to do that is to do a checkout and get the files from the server.

HOWEVER, when you said *source files*, you meant *working directory*, you may be in luck anyway. Does your *source files* contain that `.svn` directory? If so, you have a working directory, and restoring your working directory on your new machine should work just fine. Just make sure you're working with the same version of TortoiseSVN that you had on the old system: Especially if one is pre-1.7 and the other was post-1.7. That's because the working copy layout changed from version 1.6.x to version 1.7.x. See if you have the `.svn` directory in each directory of your Subversion working directory, or only in the root. If it's only in the root, use TortoiseSVN version 1.7 or greater. If it's in all the directories, use TortoiseSVN version 1.6.x.

If you don't have those `.svn` directories (and they might be hidden), then you don't have a working directory. You'll have to do a checkout, and then manually move the files over that are different. Take a look at [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com) to help you with this task.

Comment: I do still have all of the `.svn` directories in the structure. Is there a restore option?

Comment: You're in great shape! Copy the entire structure to the new computer. If there are `.svn` directories in all the directories, make sure you install TortoiseSVN 1.6.x. If you just have that `.svn` directory in the root directory, but not the sub-directories, install TortoiseSVN 1.7.

Comment: Hi, my source files just had the `.svn` directory in the root, so it seemed to be ok.. the one things I hadn't done, was re-boot my machine.. as soon as I re-booted, all of the little svn icons started showing up next to my files, so it's all good.. I was worrying about nothing ! thanks for your advice.

Comment: This saved me from hours of repository download time, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because your sources are in Working Copy (Copies) of repository (your have .svn subdir(s)), which continue to exist, just install TSVN and you can contibue too work with repos (version compatibility warning still apply, but yuo'll get notify and instructions in bad case)

You can don't worry about local changes - on `Update` you WC local changes will be merged (auto or by hand) with incoming changes

Answer (score 0):

You can do following steps:

1. Right click anywhere in your local working project explorer.
2. Select 'SVN Upgrade working copy'

follow the steps to upgrade, your svn link will be active again.

It worked for me.